# Assign account to Territory Rule in apex code

Tags: apex, case, account, territory-management

We have an issue with Accounts in wrong territories.

Basically, we have an apex controller for Cases which modifies the account field that we are using to manage territories, but reading this link https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=territories_rules.htm&language=en I can see that apex code does not execute the territory rules, so I would need a right solution to solve this.

Ideas?

Comment: Like you said We can execute territory rule from Apex.. So you need to use SOAP API.. using SOAP API update those Account that will fire the territory rules.. check this ans http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46761/how-to-execute-territory-assignment-rules-when-update-or-insert-accounts-from-da/100673#100673

Comment: Sorry we can't run territory rule from apex

Comment: So, no way to auto assign the account to the right territory? Using SOAP API in Apex code seems a dirty trick

Comment: using apex no.. Looks bad but in current situation this is the only solution.. there is an idea exchange post to run territory rules in apex. you can vote that idea.

Comment: Well, thank you Ratan, the solutions works perfectly. If you write the answer i will accept it in order to more people can read and use it.

Comment: Javier  glad it helped you

Comment: Link to the idea => https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqRXAA0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**As we all know. Currently we can't run territory assignment rule from apex. But We  can use SOAP API for this requirement

You need to use SOAP API for firing the territory management rule. You can call pass the same org(which one you are using) credentials.

Use this class `TerritoryMangRule.fireTerritoryManagementViaSoap(Pass list of Account here)`.

Follow the steps in link to generate WSDL https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts

So Once trigger is fired call a future method from there execute the webservice and pass the All Account.

```
global class TerritoryMangRule
{    
    webService static void fireTerritoryManagementViaSoap(List<Account> lstAccountToUpdate) 
    { 
        partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap obj = new partnerSoapSforceCom.Soap();
        partnerSoapSforceCom.LoginResult loginResult = obj.login('org@username.com', 'Password');   
        obj.SessionHeader = new partnerSoapSforceCom.SessionHeader_element();
        obj.endpoint_x =loginResult.ServerUrl;
        obj.Sessionheader.sessionid = loginResult.sessionid;
        List<sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x> lst = new List<sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x>();
        for(Account ac:lstAccountToUpdate)
        {
            sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x tmpObj = new sobjectPartnerSoapSforceCom.sObject_x();
            tmpObj.type_x = 'Account';
            tmpObj.Id = ac.Id;
            lst.add(tmpObj);
        }
        partnerSoapSforceCom.AssignmentRuleHeader_element  obj1 = new partnerSoapSforceCom.AssignmentRuleHeader_element();
        obj1.useDefaultRule = true;
        obj.AssignmentRuleHeader = obj1;
        partnerSoapSforceCom.SaveResult[] lst1 =obj.update_x(lst);
    } 
}
```

We need to just perform dummy update(Including set **AssignmentRuleHeader**) via SOAP API. It will run the Territory management rule.