# Assign an account to an Enterprise Territory in Apex

Tags: apex, account, territory-management, enterprise

Is there a way to assign an account to a territory2 (Enterprise Territory Managment) in apex?

Comment: check this ans http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/107579/18731

Comment: Thanks Ratan,  I also figured out you can also do it with ObjectTerritory2Association :)